# Access Database Compacting on open and close when not set to

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a split database where the front end is accessed by multiple users (I know that each user should have their own front end but that is not feasible with how the company has things set up). It also seems to compact when opened (the bottom right corner of the screen says "compacting" upon opening). Occasionally when the database is opened, it will create a copy of itself (Database.mdb). It will also do this occasionally when the database is closed. It is not a result of having multiple users on at the same time as this has occurred when I am the only person using the file. I have the database set to NOT compact on close, and I back up/compact the database manually once a week. However, the database still compacts automatically. Is there another option somewhere that I am missing or am I misunderstanding what it means to compact the database?

Comment: When the DB is opened, if the file is in a shared location, some features may be "disabled" for security features. When you click `Enable` Access performs a Compact and Repair regardless of your settings.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. What about when I close the database?

Comment: @PaulFrancis I think that should be the answer and not a comment. Can you cite a source for this information and post it as an answer. This should have been closed years ago.